# AutoMapper and CA1506: Avoid excessive class coupling

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, code-analysis

In a .NET Core 2.2 project, we are using AutoMapper.  In the Startup file's ConfigureService method, where we register everything, we call:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ModelMaps));
```

The ModelMaps class is where we make all the calls to `CreateMap()` to put all of our model mappings in one place.  It has many mappings in it like these:

```
CreateMap<WarehouseModel, Warehouse>().ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Import, ImportModel>()
    .ForMember(
        m => m.StatusDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(
            o => EnumUtility.GetDescriptionFromEnum(o.StatusId)));
```

After we got to using 100 different types, we began getting this error:

> Error CA1506: 'ModelMaps' is coupled with '100' different types from '8' different namespaces. Rewrite or refactor the code to decrease its class coupling below '96'. (8, 18)

I know why class coupling is a bad idea, but what about this instance?  Is there a better way for us to be registering these maps?  Is this really even a problem?  Should we simply suppress this instance of the error and move on?

Comment: you could split it up into multiple profiles for automapper

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have a profile per module. Of course that assumes you already have those :)

Comment: I don't think you can/should do anything about this. This is your application's composition root and it's by design and definition the place where you _wire up_ all your types together.